# onKeyDown isn't invoked

Tags: android, onkeydown

i'm passing a rootView to setContentView:

```
root = (FlyOutMenu) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_myLayout, null);
    setContentView(root);
```

and the layout is defined like :

```
<com.android.xyz.view.viewgroup.FlyOutMenu.FlyOutMenu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_label_topic" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_searchbar_topic"
                    android:ems="10" >
                </EditText>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_menu_topic" />


                <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gv1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/dialog_searchbar_topic"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
            </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, it's a code in a different package in the same application.

I have two packages in my application:

`1) com.android.xyz.view.viewgroup.FlyOutMenu`
`2) con.android.xyz`

in my second package in the MainActivity i Override the `onKeyDown`- method but it never gets invoked.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("onKeyUp","Fired");
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.e("fired with KeyEvent","true");
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams myLayoutParams = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) gv.getLayoutParams();
        myLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        gv.setLayoutParams(myLayoutParams);
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

I haven't attached any onFocus listener. The only View which requests Focus is my searchbar in my activity but it also doesn't have a Focus listener.

**I tried following:**

[onKeyDown not always called in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592559/onkeydown-not-always-called-in-android-app)

With no result... issue stays the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Does anybody know why this can't be invoked?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this answer is not too late for your problem ;)

I ran into this same issue with my own custom view implementation and what I found out was that `onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` is the keyboard handling event that is invoked on a `View`

However `ViewGroup` never invokes `onKeyUp`, instead it invokes its own method `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` and this is the one you need to `@Override` in your custom `ViewGroup` implementation.

Hope this helps out if someone else runs into this problem.